# iOS - Subscription payment based on phone number or promo code

Tags: ios, subscription

We plan to implement all the subscription server-side services. Here is the flow for our client iOS app:

The registered user enters phone number, we check if the number is valid and if it is, the user can subscribe and thus use some features of the app that an user without an active subscription can't. The subscription is not free and it doesn't go via AppStore; the user is charged at the side of his/her provider, based on his/her phone number. The user isn't asked to give any of his/her credit card data. One of the features that gets unlocked when user subscribes is the possibility to download digital content.

The question is: would Apple approve this flow? I know for subscriptions as in-app purchase types, but the plan is to have something different in our iOS app.

And what about promo codes? Is it possible for vip users to use our promo codes in order to subscribe..?

Answer (score 1):

Apple will *not* approve any purchases that get added to an iOS device, are initiated on the iOS device, and don't go through the app store. You can do purchases through your web site; in that case you will have to avoid links to your website from the app.

On the other hand, physical purchases must *not* go through the app store. So if you have an app for buying hand bags, you can *not* get payments through the app store.

Apple will also give you a very hard time if you ask users for their personal information, like their phone number, and if there are features they can't get without giving you such information.